# Grouping columns from a nested select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `table1` with the following columns:

```
id (INT)
label (VARCHAR)
value (INT)
```

I want to retrieve both the average of the `value` column, the entire row where the `value` is the largest, and the row with the lowest `value`. Something like this:

```
{
    average: xxx,
    maxval: {
        id: x,
        label: x,
        value: x
    },
    minval: {
        id: x,
        label: x,
        value: x
    }
}
```

Tried with the following query:

```
SELECT 
AVG(a.value) AS average, 
b.*,
c.*
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table1 b ON ( b.value = (SELECT MAX(value) FROM table1 WHERE label = "el")) 
INNER JOIN table1 c ON ( c.value = (SELECT MIN(value) FROM table1 WHERE label = "el")) 
WHERE a.label = "el";
```

but this will return all the fields in a single level, like this:

```
{
    average,
    id,
    label,
    value,
    id,
    label,
    value
}
```

Tried this too:

```
SELECT 
AVG(a.value) AS average, 
(SELECT b.* FROM table1 b WHERE ( b.value = (SELECT MAX(value) FROM table1 WHERE label = "el"))) AS maxval,
(SELECT c.* FROM table1 c WHERE ( c.value = (SELECT MIN(value) FROM table1 WHERE label = "el"))) AS minval
FROM table1 a
WHERE a.label = "el";
```

This last one give an error as I'm trying to use a single alias on multiple columns.

Using MySQL 5.5.

Comment: You cant return a composite result unless you use JSON

Comment: How are you returning that output from SQL? Are you using application layer like PHP?

Comment: @Parfait sending query from nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need do separated querys for each one

```
SELECT q1.*, q2.*, q3.*
FROM (SELECT AVG(value)
      FROM  Table1) as q1
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT *
             FROM Table1
             ORDER BY value
             LIMIT 1) as q2
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT *
             FROM Table1
             ORDER BY value DESC
             LIMIT 1) as q3
```

You can use `JSON_OBJECT(key1, value1, key2, value2, ... key(n), value(n))`

```
 SELECT q1.*, 
    JSON_OBJECT("id", q2.id, "label", q2.label,"value", q2.value),
    JSON_OBJECT("id", q3.id, "label", q3.label,"value", q3.value)
```

Comment: With this I have the same issue as on my first try. All the resulted columns on a single level.

Comment: managed to do a similar workaround with CONCAT because JSON_OBJECT is not available in 5.5.